# How to find which line throws an error in a loop

Tags: r

I have to find 6 errors in the following code and I think I found three already, which are in p and q sample and the brakes in Y.

I changed them to:

```
  p = sample(1:6, 1)
  q = sample(1:6, 1)
  Y = y[(n + 1)(2*n)]
```

and got the following error message afterwards:

```
Error in err[(t - 1):(p - q)] : 
  only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

Can you help me fix this and find the other errors?
Also I have to delete one unnecessary variable from rm (at the last line)

---

```
myMatrikel = 7081255 

{
  n = 500
  
  set.seed(myMatrikel)
  
  p = sample(1:6, n = 1)
  q = sample(1:6, n = 1)
  
  alpha = round(runif(q, min = 0, max = 1/q), digits = 3)
  beta  = round(runif(p, min = 0, max = 1/p), digits = 3)
  
  initY = rnorm(max(p, q))
  initErr = rnorm(max(p, q))
  
  y = err = 1:(2*n)*0
  y[1:max(p, q)] = initY
  err[1:max(p, q)] = initErr
  
  for (t in (max(p, q) + 1):length(y))
  {
    err[t] = rnorm(1)
    y[t] = beta %*% y[(t - 1):(t - p)] + alpha %*% err[(t - 1):(p - q)] + Err[t]
  }
  
  Y = y[(n + 1)(2*n])
}  

rm(list = c("err", "initErr", "initY", "y", "t", "myMatrikel"))
```

Comment: Rerun with debug or look at the error, it often shows the steps that led to the error which helps to narrow it down. Alternatively, run your code in chunks and see which chunk actually fails?

Comment: a convenient thing with R is that you can see the values of that the variables have when the loop stops. So it's possible to check what were the values of t, p, q... to understand why this specific line return an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea, how to narrow it down:

```
for (t in (max(p, q) + 1):length(y)) {
    if (t %% 50) cat(t, "\n")
    else cat(t)
    err[t] = rnorm(1)
    y[t] = beta %*% y[(t - 1):(t - p)] + alpha %*% err[(t - 1):(p - q)] + Err[t]
}
```

This way you can see at which iteration the error occurs and look at the specific values of that iteration. Then might easier able to see, what is causing the error.